# jpql query gives different result in different platforms

Tags: spring-boot, jpql

There's something very weird I encountered with while 'playing' with jpql queries which im very new to .

the first one I tried in **Spring boot app** working with **spring repository**

```
@Query("select he.myGroup from HostEntity he where he.host = ?1 order by he.inGroupSince ")
    List<String> getHostGrpIdOrderList(String hostName);
```

which return just **one** string, the one with the highest **inGroupSince** filed

the second and very similar query was in http://jpqlquery.com/

```
 select e.name from Employee e  where e.department.id = 4 order by e.name
```

and here it retunrs Lists of employee names ! and not just the first one like the first query .

So why there's a difference ? why does the query in spring boot app returns only one string and not an ordered list ??

Comment: The fact that a query looks similar doesn't mean it is. Both will return a list IF there are multiple results. Apparently for the first one, given the `hostName` there is only a single result.

Comment: no, there several results...each host has a row per group/ingroupsince combination, and i saved several of those in the repository..